# Python tkinter can I use vector images?

Tags: python-3.x, image, tkinter, vector

**Is it necessarily to convert my .ai file to a png? My code works with png/jpg/gif but with .ai it says file type isnt recognized**

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()

vector_image = PhotoImage(file='adobe_illustrator.ai')

label = Label(root)
label.config(image=vector_image)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't think, you can display svg (or ai for that matter) natively in `tkinter`, but you can rasterize your image dynamically from the vector graphic, so that it's always sharp. If you want to display svg, maybe switch to Qt for example

Comment: I do not believe PIL supports SVG either but my understand is `svglib` does and can be used. Last I read it was still being developed in 2017 so might have some luck with that. You can also look into a converter to convert the SVG to a PNG or other format.

Answer (score 0):

No, tkinter does not support vector graphics. There may be third-party python libraries that can convert it for you.